# R ggplot2 reorder bars and putting one specific at the end

Tags: r, ggplot2

how can I arrange this table to make gg plot sort my bars by 'PART' while putting 'others' at the end ? (my real dataset is bigger so I need something 'automatic').

```
   fruits          name          value
   <chr>           <chr>         <dbl>
 1 Others          PART          0.727 
 2 Others          PROD          0.447 
 3 Others          PROD_NATIONAL 0.565 
 4 Apple           PART          0.0536
 5 Apple           PROD          0.25  
 6 Apple           PROD_NATIONAL 0.175 
 7 Banana          PART          0.0530
 8 Banana          PROD          0.35  
 9 Banana          PROD_NATIONAL 0.260
```

I already went through several explanations but no one has a dataset like mine (where 'PART' is inside a column, not a column on its own). And I can't just pivot_wider since I need to put 'PART' in my graph and thus use the 'fill' function with the three ('PART', 'PROD', 'PROD_NAT').

At the end I need something like that
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RezL.png)

Thanks for any tips !

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fct_relevel` from `forcats`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
df1 %>%
  mutate(fruits = fct_relevel(fruits, "Others", after = Inf),
         name = factor(name, levels = c("PART", "PROD", "PROD_NATIONAL"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fruits, y = value, fill = name)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(fruits = c("Others", "Others", "Others", "Apple", 
"Apple", "Apple", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana"), name = c("PART", 
"PROD", "PROD_NATIONAL", "PART", "PROD", "PROD_NATIONAL", "PART", 
"PROD", "PROD_NATIONAL"), value = c(0.727, 0.447, 0.565, 0.0536, 
0.25, 0.175, 0.053, 0.35, 0.26)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: hi, it didn't work in my dataset (not sure why).

I finally achieve what I wanted by adding one line before the plot

df$fruits = factor(df$fruits,levels=unique(df$fruits))

But I honestly don't unsterdand why...

Comment: @Jujename It may be because your original dataset have more levels than you showed in the post.